# MVC Routes With Embedded IDs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

We want to have a route that looks like this:

```
/account/123/dosomething/234
```

In this case, `account` would be the controller and `requesttrafficid` would be the action, I guess. I am assuming I can define this route like this:

```
{controller}/{accountId}/{action}/{id}
```

In this case, the two IDs just become parameters of the action.

The question is: can do something like this for Web API?

Our normal MVC controllers are just returning views and other static content.
All of our data comes from the API.
We want our routes to be as close as possible, something like this:

```
api/account/123/dosomething/234
```

Based on my understanding, `account` wouldn't be the API controller, it would be `dosomething`. The two IDs just become parameters again. But how do I define this route? Do I just hard-code the 'account' part?

Comment: Why would you assume `account` wouldn't be the API controller? Given your API is deployed at `/api` and your API controller is named `AccountApiController`, the same route would match.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I am under the impression is that Web API controllers can only have names starting with `Get`/`Put`/`Post`/`Delete`. There's no such thing as an action name, per se. So `dosomething` can't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `AttributeRouting`, this is a piece of cake: http://attributerouting.net. You just put the placeholders at the right spot in your URL and MVC handles the rest.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only concern is being able to make the action portion of the route the same, you have two choices:

1. You're not *required* to use the naming convention of `[Method]Action`. If you don't follow this convention, you just need to specify which method applies with the appropriate attribute:

   ```
   // These are functionally equivalent:

   public JsonResult GetSomething(int id) { ... }

   [HttpGet]
   public JsonResult DoSomething(int id) { ... }
   ```
2. If you want to follow convention, but you want to customize the action name for routing purposes, you can use the `ActionName` attribute:

   ```
   [ActionName("dosomething")]
   public JsonResult GetSomething(int id) { ... }
   ```

Comment: What if there are multiple actions of type 'POST'? How do I distinguish between them?